# asynchronously prepend to stream

Tags: scala, asynchronous, stream

I've got a function that returns an performs operations on an infinite stream, originating from a socket.

```
def f1(s:Stream[T]):Stream[T] = s map {...} filter {...}
```

I've got another method that returns a finite sequence that I'd like to join to this stream.

```
def f2():Stream[T] = ...
```

Here's what I'm looking for:

```
val a = f2#:::f1(s)
```

The problem is, `f2` will take some time to compute, and `f1` needs to be outputting values as soon as possible.  I'd like to wrap `f2` in a `Runnable` so I can compute its value without blocking the rest of the program.

I'd like `a` to behave as follows: if `f2` is done being computed, prepend it to `f1` and keep outputting values of that stream.  Else, keep outputting values of `f1`.  How should I proceed?

Comment: what should happen if `f2` was not done computing, and we keep outputting values of `f1`, and then `f2` completes its computation?

Comment: prepend onto f1 when it finishes -- so the definition of the steam is `f2 while any f2 else f1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a custom class that extends `Stream`, and define all the necessary methods for your desired semantics.  Going with this approach will give you the most flexibility when it comes to defining custom semantics.  You can even then enrich `Stream` so it has a `withAsynPrefix` method.  Below is a rough version for `Iterator`, which is a little simpler:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case class CombinedIterator[T](val iterator: Iterator[T], val prefix: Future[Iterator[T]]) extends Iterator[T] {
    def hasNext: Boolean = iterator.hasNext || Await.result(prefix, Duration.Inf).hasNext
    def next: T = prefix.value.collect {
        case Success(pfx) if pfx.hasNext => pfx.next
    }.getOrElse(iterator.next)
}

implicit class AsyncPrefixable[T](val iterator: Iterator[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def withAsyncPrefix(prefix: Future[Iterator[T]]): Iterator[T] = CombinedIterator(iterator, prefix)
}
```

So then you can do:

```
val iterator = Iterator.from(0).take(10000)
val prefix = Future { Thread.sleep(10); Iterator(-1) }
val iteratorWithPrefix = iterator.withAsyncPrefix(prefix)
iteratorWithPrefix.toList.indexOf(-1) //Run a few times, location can vary greatly within list
```

Comment: Ben, this looks great.  Could I just call `.toStream` on this `Iterator` to yield a `Stream`?

Comment: @WalrustheCat Probably!  You could probably also extend `Stream` instead of `Iterator`.  I haven't tested this at all so you should make sure it catches any edge cases!